# How do you add a column to data frames in a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, wrangle

I have a list of data frames. I want to add a new column to each data frame. For example, I have three data frames as follows:

```
a = data.frame("Name" = c("John","Dor"))
b = data.frame("Name" = c("John2","Dor2"))
c = data.frame("Name" = c("John3","Dor3"))
```

I then put them into a list:

```
dfs = list(a,b,c)
```

I then want to add a new column with a unique value to each data frame, e.g.:

```
dfs[1]$new_column <- 5
```

But I get the following error:

```
"number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"
```

I have also tried using two brackets:

```
dfs[[1]]$new_column <- 5
```

This does not return an error but it does not add the column.

This would be in a 'for' loop and a different value would be added to each data frame.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, sorry I should have specified. This will be in a for loop and there will be a different value for each data frame.

Comment: Try indexing with `[[` instead of `[`

Comment: @Camille thanks. I already tried this and it does not return an error but the data frame column does not get added.

Comment: @RonakShah added a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to add a new column with value `5:7` for each dataframe. We can use `Map`

```
new_value <- 5:7
Map(cbind, dfs, new_column = new_value)

#[[1]]
#  Name new_column
#1 John          5
#2  Dor          5

#[[2]]
#   Name new_column
#1 John2          6
#2  Dor2          6

#[[3]]
#   Name new_column
#1 John3          7
#2  Dor3          7
```

With `lapply` you could do

```
lapply(seq_along(dfs), function(i) cbind(dfs[[i]], new_column = new_value[i]))
```

Or as @camille mentioned it works if you use `[[` for indexing in the `for` loop

```
for (i in seq_along(dfs)) {
    dfs[[i]]$new_column <- new_value[[i]]
}
```

---

The equivalent `purrr` version of this would be

```
library(purrr)
map2(dfs, new_value, cbind)
```

and

```
map(seq_along(dfs), ~cbind(dfs[[.]], new_colum = new_value[.]))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a question for you, however: when I use the double brackets the initial data frame (e.g., "a") does not get a column added, but the "a" within the list does get the column added. Why is that?

Comment: @jtam because `dfs` is a separate object and `a` is a separate object. In the `for` loop we are only adding a column for `dfs` object and it is independent of `a`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation -- appreciate it!